# Best sort algorithm for many lookups

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

I need some advice to chose a sorting algorithm to code for this problem.

In phase one, the program will fetch clientIDs and respective hashes (will be using a struct, probably) from a database. There can be 0 or many thousands of records.

In phase two, the program will complete this set with records read from a XML file. I've already built the stream parser. The XML file has all the client info sequentially before invoice data.

When phase two is done, the program will read the invoice data. For each invoice there's one clientID and this has to be checked from the set of clients. The number of invoices can be millions of records.

What I initially thought.  Since I don't know how many client records there will be, I must add memory dynamically using a linked list. At the end of phase two I can create an array of data ordered by clientID, so that I can perform further searches, one for each invoice, can be retrieved quick, maybe using a binary search.

I'd like to know what do you advise me to handle this situation. What sort algorithms should I use? (I'll be coding in C).

Comment: One word: [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) ... or some other [embedded database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database).

Comment: Let's see if I can restate the problem. You have a many-to-1 relationship, and need a sorted array for a Foreign Key lookup of clientID in the little table, while the large table (XMLfooMassaged) can be read sequentially? Even if the database didn't tell you how many records, ftell() will. Just use calloc(). I agree with Oli, use qsort() and bsearch(), and if you read my profile, you'll see I've used such code to process trillions of records. Thousands of records will sort in a second or two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguably, the best algorithm is one that satisfies the following criteria:

- You don't have to write any code
- You don't incur any 3rd-party dependencies
- Is fast enough for your purposes

Given that thousands of records is basically none, I'd suggest using [`qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) for the sort, and [`bsearch`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/bsearch) for the searches; both of these are in the C standard library.

Issues to note:

- `qsort` can't be used on a linked-list.  I'd strongly suggest storing your data in a dynamically-grown array; the amortized cost of creation is the same, and you'll have other benefits (e.g. less memory overhead, better [*locality of reference*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference)).
- If, after careful profiling, you find that `bsearch` is not sufficiently fast, then you may want to move over to a hashtable-based lookup, as this is O(1), not O(log N).  However, don't attempt to write your own; use an existing library for this.  (See other answers here for suggestions.)

Answer (score 1):

The [`glib` library](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/) includes a [hash table implementation](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-Hash-Tables.html). While unsorted, [hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) will let you do O(1) or [constant-time lookups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity), which will be useful if you have millions of invoices to look up.

There are other possibilities, like a sorted array of `Client` structs through which you do a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search). Let's say your `Client` struct contains an `unsigned int` member called `clientID`. If your client IDs are unique and [monotonically increasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) (not necessarily equivalent to the array index, but increasing), and you have `n` records, then you simply need to go to a pivot index `floor(n/2)` and see if your ID-of-interest `i` is greater than, equal to or less than that the ID referenced by the struct reference at the pivot index, in order to decide which half of the array to look through next. Your new pivot index will be the midpoint of the lower and upper bounds of that subarray, which you would recursively search until you find your element of interest.

The lookup performance of a binary search through a sorted array is O(log n) — slower than a hash table, and there is the non-zero cost of sorting an array, but the overall memory overhead can be smaller. If you have the memory for it, a hash table will likely be faster and is therefore often a good structure for very large numbers of lookups.